# Where is modification required in this shell script to add the value which is not there in file

Tags: linux, shell

I am writing shell script to check "kernel.shmall" value. Purpose of script is if kernel.shmall is less than 4194304 then it should modify the value to 4194304. If kernel.shmall is not there is file /etc/system.conf then it should add the value to file kernel.shmall=4194304

```
if grep -o "kernel.shmall" /emblocal/sysctl.conf > /dev/null
then
     oldvalue=$(grep -v '^#' /emblocal/sysctl.conf|grep kernel.shmall|sed 's/=/ /g'| awk '{ print $2}')

     if [ $oldvalue -lt 4194304 ]
     then
        sed -i "s|\("kernel.shmall" *= *\).*|\14194304|" /emblocal/sysctl.conf
     fi
else
     echo "kernel.shmall=" >> /emblocal/sysctl.conf
     sed -i "s|\("kernel.shmall" *= *\).*|\14194304|" /emblocal/sysctl.conf
fi
```

script is wokring if value is less than 4194304, but it is not adding "kernel.shmall=4194304" if it is not there. can you help me in this to get it done?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
oldvalue=$(sed '/^#/d;/kernel\.shmall/!d;s/^[^=]*= *//' /emblocal/sysctl.conf)
if [ "$oldvalue" ]; then
    [ $oldvalue -lt 4194304 ] &&
    sed -i '/kernel\.shmall/{s/=.*/= 4194304/}' /emblocal/sysctl.conf
else
    echo "kernel.shmall = 4194304" >> /emblocal/sysctl.conf
fi
```

Or more succinctly in AWK:

```
f=$(mktemp)
awk -vn=kernel.shmall '
    function max(a,b) {return a<b?b:a}
    {
        if ($1 == n) oldval = $3
        else print
    }
    END {print n, "=", max(oldval, 4194304)}
    ' /emblocal/sysctl.conf > "$f" && cp "$f" /emblocal/sysctl.conf
rm "$f"
```

Comment: Perhaps `cp` (and `rm`) instead of `mv` to preserve permissions on `sysctl.conf`?

Comment: @Ismael : Getting error as below for both the scripts
: [: 4194304: unknown operator

Comment: That doesn't make much sense... would you mind to copy the whole output?

Comment: @Ismael: Error is
./m.sh[5]: [: 4194304: unknown operator
Code is
if grep -q 'kernel\.shmall' /etc/sysctl.conf
then
     oldvalue=$(sed '/^#/d;/kernel\.shmall/!d;s/^[^=]*=/ /' /etc/sysctl.conf)

     [ $oldvalue -lt 4194304 ] &&
       sed -i '/kernel\.shmall/{s/=.*/= 4194304/}' /etc/sysctl.conf
else
     echo "kernel.shmall = 4194304" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
fi

Comment: @user3541225: what kind of shell are you using?

Comment: @user3541225 when you get cryptic errors like those, you might want to try it in other shell, like bash, sometimes it gives useful information about the problem.